# iPhone4 EXC_BAD_ACCESS for UIView after dealloc. How to debug?

Tags: exception, uiview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, iphone-4

I'm working with Apple's Accelerometer Graph Example:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html

I'm pushing 2 Graph Views onto a navigation controller:

```
  GraphViewController* graphViewController = [[GraphViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"GraphViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:graphViewController animated:YES];
    [graphViewController release];
```

The graph's are updated by an external method:

```
     [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:motionQueue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
...

      if(graphDelegate)
                    {
                        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(notifyGraphDelegateWithMotionEvent:) withObject:motion];

                    }

}
```

, which calls

```
 [unfiltered addX:filteredValue y:unfilteredvalue z:10];
```

for each graph. The frequency of updates is 20 times per second

When I pop the view from the navigation controller, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS after [super dealloc]

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    // Since 'text' and 'current' are weak references, we do not release them here.
    // [super dealloc] will take care to release 'text' as a subview, and releasing 'segments' will release 'current'.
    [segments release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This is a nasty error, and I really don't know how to troubleshoot something like that. It seems to be something about the order in which the views are de-allocated, as the crash happens after the view is popped. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot something like that?

Comment: Have you tried NSZombieEnabled to YES in your environmental variables ? If not try that first.

Comment: What Nikita said.  You're probably over-releasing an object, and `NSZombie` is designed to detect that.

Comment: @Alex Stone code you have showed us looks fine to me. Fixing EXC_BAD_ACCESS is fun. Let us know what happens when you enable NSZombieEnabled. If that doesn't work you can either post your entire sample project ( zip it and share link here ) someone will go through your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled), [MallocStackLogging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MallocStackLogging), and [guard malloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) in the debugger.  Then, when your App crashes, type this in the gdb console:

```
(gdb) info malloc-history 0x543216
```

Replace `0x543216` with the address of the object that caused the crash, and you will get a much more useful stack trace and it should help you pinpoint the exact line in your code that is causing the problem.

[See this article for more detailed instructions.](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this next time some crazy bug like that would creep into my code!